# Automatically logs out users after submitting update form

Tags: laravel

Very weird issue.

Im logged into Laravel app with 2 different users in Chrome and Chrome Incognito.

When I submit {any} update form it logs the **other** user out when I refresh. 
The user that I submitted the form with is still logged in.
When simply browsing around both users remain logged in.

**Environment**

- Windows XAMP
- session drive = redis (I have tried changing this to see if it helps)

**UPDATE:**

- Same thing happens when logged in from 2 seperate browsers - Chrome / IE
- I presume something in the Illuminate\Http\Request class causes this behavior.

**UPDATE 2**

Keeps both users logged in when I select the "Remember Me" option.

- similar issue: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-not-reading-session-cookie-on-form-post-in-chrome-when-logged-in-with-remember-me
  Hints to being XAMP bug - using different dev environment solved it.
- I think with it being such a weird issue - and not many people experiencing it must be a issue with my specific environment.

Comment: any code? well, unless you meddle with `Auth` there should be no issue.. also, laravel version? configuration (session for instance)? and `{any} update form` a bit.. unclear.

Comment: Update the post - the any - really means any form.

Answer (score 0):

The sessions in PHP use a cookie (created automatically) that is stored by your browser, is very posible that the mode igcognito that you are using delete this cookie whe you refresh the page.

Comment: No, I am able to login and browse around in both Chrome browser and Incognito Browser. So sessions are kept.

Answer (score 0):

When starting the first Incognito window, it uses a completely brand new and blank internal profile that has no cookies nor session data. Any cookies or session info are set immediately during that session. Further Incognito windows opened all share that same session, so they share the cookies/session data.

Comment: Yes I understand that using the same browser will use the same session cookies. ie Not allow 2 users to login. But I am using normal Chrome and then a Incognito window...fyi.. I have also tested loggin in with the second user on a completely different browser with the same issue.